# How to prompt message box in remote computer where application is running as service?

Tags: windows, winapi, service, mfc, messagebox

I have an C++ MFC application running in master machine that installs update from a server in remote computers through an agent service. This service takes care of authorization in remote machines before update. Now, I need to prompt the currently active user in remote machines for confirmation. AfxMessagebox or MessageBox in the service context doesn't show up any window in remote machines. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Services run in session 0, and any UI shown there is not visible. You need to show the UI from a process running in a user session. Typically that means creating a helper process in the user session, and having it show the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`WTSSendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtssendmessagew):

> Displays a message box on the client desktop of a specified Remote Desktop Services session.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
Can this messagebox be customized? Or I have only the option of UINT type i.e MB_YESNO, MB_YESNOCANCEL etc. Instead of 'yes'/'no', can there be customized texts?

Comment: @user2541490 sorry, the only customizations are title, message text, and standard buttons, just like a normal MessageBox